# Populate fields based on lookup table

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding how to populate fields in one database table based on values from another. Essentially, I have one table which serves as a lookup table. It has a list of codes (**Column A**) and corresponding messages as seen below. It is somewhat static, with 20+ codes and messages and potential of new values being added manually on occasion:

TABLE A - LOOKUP TABLE

```
Column A |  Column B
  AA101  |  Message 1
  AA102  |  Message 2
  AA103  |  Message 3
  AA104  |  Message 4
  AA105  |  Message 5
```

The other table has variable records, where above-mentioned codes are retrieved based on user input. It has many columns, but last two columns ought to be the same:

TABLE B - DATA TABLE

```
Column Y |  Column Z
  AA105  |  [Retrieve Message 5]
  AA102  |  [Retrieve Message 2]
  AA101  |  [Retrieve Message 1]
```

What I'd like to do is traverse through the list of codes in **Column Y**, compare with those in Column A from lookup table) and foreach of these codes retrieve the appropriate message (i.e. load messages to **Column Z**). Can anyone let me know how this can be achieved with a SQL query?

Note: All records from TABLE B are removed/truncated each night, so there's no risk of it becoming too big or overloaded with data.

Many thanks in advance for your help. 
It's highly appreciated!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Sounds like a simple join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing these aren't the real table/ column names, but even so, this is a simple `UPDATE` query?

```
UPDATE
    B
SET
    [Column Z] = A.[Column B]
FROM
    [TABLE B] B
    INNER JOIN [TABLE A] A ON A.[Column A] = B.[Column Y];
```

Depending on which flavour of SQL your database supports.

Comment: Why?  This is to "populate" or "load" data (OP's terminology) which I interpreted as an `UPDATE` query.